# APE with multiple domains

Tags: cakephp, cross-domain, ape

In my application I am using APE for getting the async updates from other users.
Now it is working for a particular domain (abc.com), but now my user (company) wants to use xyz.com for company.abc.com, i have done this by creating **CNAME**. But now **APE** gives the following error

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i resolved this issue.

APE has cross domain transport available & possible, please refer,

http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:Use_different_transport_method_%28JSONP%2C_XHRStreaming%29

I was using the

APE.Config.transport = 1; which i changed to

APE.Config.transport = 2;  // 2 is JSONP

It worked cool for me :)